# How to include start and end date in pandas groupby/Grouper?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

I have a example DataFrame below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01",
             "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01"],
    'amount': [2,4,3,5,6,4],
    'category': ['credit', 'credit', 'debit', 'credit', 'debit', 'credit']})

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

print(df)
       date  amount category
0 2022-01-01       2   credit
1 2022-02-01       4   credit
2 2022-03-01       3    debit
3 2022-04-01       5   credit
4 2022-05-01       6    debit
5 2022-05-01       4    debit
6 2022-06-01       4   credit
```

I want to get the average sum of amount of debit's per month. However, when I try the groupby using grouper I get:

```
print(df[df['category']=='debit'].groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="MS")).sum())

            amount
date              
2022-03-01       3
2022-04-01       0
2022-05-01       10
```

My desired output has **all** the months from the original DataFrame but 0 in the months there are no debits

```
            amount
date  
2022-01-01       0
2022-02-01       0     
2022-03-01       3
2022-04-01       0
2022-05-01       10
2022-06-01       0
```

I have tried using ["Origin"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to set start date but no luck :(

Comment: It's not clear why you want to group and sum in your example since you have only one row per month. Please provide a realistic example. The desired output can be obtain with `df.loc[df['category']=='credit','amount'] = 0` which is probably not what you want...

Comment: @Tranbi I appreciate your comment. I have added another row to further show what to group and sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.mask` and convert `DatetimeIndex` as `PeriodIndex`

```
out = (df['amount'].mask(df['category'] == 'credit', other=0)
                   .groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('M'))
                   .sum().reset_index())
# Output
      date  amount
0  2022-01       0
1  2022-02       0
2  2022-03       3
3  2022-04       0
4  2022-05      10
5  2022-06       0
```

Another way with `pd.Grouper`:

```
out = (df.assign(amount=df['amount'] * df['category'].eq('debit'))
         .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='MS'))['amount']
         .sum().reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
        date  amount
0 2022-01-01       0
1 2022-02-01       0
2 2022-03-01       3
3 2022-04-01       0
4 2022-05-01      10
5 2022-06-01       0
```

The idea is to set `amount` to 0 when the `category` is "credit".

Comment: Well done! I really appreciate your time and effort :)